# How to switch layout when User is in two Roles (eg admin and also a service user)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to switch layout according to User in two Roles like one is admin and also a service user, i have dropdown on my page when user gets login and in dropdown I have option "Switch to User Mode" when user logged in as an Admin  and "Switch to Admin Mode" when user logged in as a Service User,

Comment: You can use _ViewStart.cshtml file to do that
Add your conditions in this file and set layout page accordingly.

Comment: No ! i want if click on "Switch to User Mode" option in my Dropdown, i have to be switched to User Mode, as i am Admin and User also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to be able to click a button to switch the layout, then you have two options:

1. Make the button a link to the current page and add something to the query string, e.g. `?mode=user`. Then, you can switch the layout in your view (or `_ViewStart.cshtml`) like:

   ```
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   if (Request["mode"] == "user")
   {
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_UserLayout.cshtml";
   }
   ```
2. Have the button go to a URL or post a form to a URL served by an action that will then set a session variable. You can then branch the layout in your view based on the session variable, similar to the code above.

Option 2 is more persistent. With option 1, you'd either have to pass the query string param around link to link or the layout will switch back. However, that might be something you want, if you only want the switch to effect the current view. By setting a session variable, the layout choice will stick until the session expires or you change it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have different actions and views to each role, so I recommend you also to separate them into areas.
In this way you can achieve few things:

1. Your solution is better constructed
2. Each area is responsible for 1 role
3. Each area has its own URL (like: site.com/Admin, site.com/User)
4. Each area has its controllers/views/Layout
5. You can share controllers/views/resources among areas

So now you can have some global layout in which user can choose her mode. And all you have to do is redirect her to the right area controller!